# React DevTools: How to append component filters programmatically?

Tags: react-devtools

I use React DevTools Chrome Extension. I want to append component filters from a react app code. Is there a way to do this?

In common I want to share default application DevTools settings across the app developers.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I figured out. Here's an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/devtools-interop-example-vqzq6?file=/src/index.js):

```js
if (__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__) {
  const handleReactDevtools = (agent) => {
    __REACT_DEVTOOLS_COMPONENT_FILTERS__.push({
      type: 2,
      isEnabled: true,
      isValid: true,
      value: "HideMe"
    });
    agent.updateComponentFilters(__REACT_DEVTOOLS_COMPONENT_FILTERS__);
  };
  if (__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.reactDevtoolsAgent) {
    handleReactDevtools(__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.reactDevtoolsAgent);
  } else {
    __REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.on("react-devtools", handleReactDevtools);
  }
}
```

[image: DevTools interop example]